# Make a "DeleteTransaction" case and remove an item from the state using filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I want to make a `DeleteTransaction` case and remove an item from the state using `filter`.

My current code is below:

```
const TransactionReducer = ((state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "AddTransactions": {
            return [action.payload, ...state]
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
})

export default TransactionReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new case and `filter()` your `state`. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array, so the following should work:

```
const TransactionReducer = ((state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "AddTransactions": 
            return [action.payload, ...state]
        
        case "DeleteTransaction": 
            return state.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)
        
        default:
            return state;
    }
})

export default TransactionReducer;
```

You can pass an `id` as the `payload` and check if it's the same as the `id` in your `state` array. (Although I don't know how your `state` looks like, so it's just a guess.)